# ¿Cómo leer un archivo html y guardarlo como CSV o TXT?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy tratando de leer un archivo html con `pd.read_html()` y luego quiero guardar esa información en un archivo CSV o txt, pero toma toda la memoria de mi PC solo tratando de leerlo, y esperé como Un día y todavía no hay progreso.

¿Hay alguna otra forma de hacer este proceso?

Adjunté una foto de los datos. Alrededor de (800mb)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

`pd.read_html()` debe tratar de leer todo el archivo en memoria. Para
que eso no pase, podrías procesar el archivo de forma perezosa usando
la clase `HTMLParser` del módulo `html.parser`. Esta llama a unas funciones
definidas por el usuario cuando encuentra un tag de inicio o de fin, o los
datos que se encuentran entre estos tags. Así se puede procesar el archivo por
partes.

Un ejemplo que muestra el archivo csv generado por la salida estándar:

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser
import csv
import sys

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self, writer):
        self.tags = []
        self.writer = writer
        self.row = []
        super().__init__()

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        self.tags.append(tag)

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        if tag == "tr":
            self.writer.writerow(self.row)
            self.row = []

        self.tags.pop()

    def handle_data(self, data):
        tag = self.tags[-1] if self.tags else: ""

        if tag in {"th", "td"}:
            self.row.append(data)

parser = MyHTMLParser(csv.writer(sys.stdout))

with open("tabla_pec.html", "r", encoding="cp1252") as file_:
    for line in file_:
        parser.feed(line)
```

Comment: Gracias, esa parece ser una buena solución. Luego de intentar con una parte de la tabla de html me arroja este error, no estoy muy seguro de cómo identificar lo que está mal.

Comment: [https://www.kaggle.com/miguelpy/aaaaaa]..... En ese enlace está la parte de la tabla con la cual estoy probando. Tal vez, puedas darle un vistazo?

Comment: Ahi me fije, mira que el html completo (el de 800mb) está público, no sé si lo hayas hecho a propósito. Con respecto al programa, parece que no funciona porque expat no soporta html, solo xml. Ahí edito mi respuesta con una forma que funcione.

Comment: Pensé que estaba privado.. en fin, esa es la estructura del archivo...